# Pandas to_datetime with estabilished time interval

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm currently working on a code which reads timestamps from csv. But the problem is that I need to store data in a 12-hour time interval. Here's my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("2021-08-13.csv", parse_dates=['time'], infer_datetime_format=True)
    datafilter = data[data.lane == "Lane 1"]
    datafilter['time'] = pd.to_datetime(datafiltr['time'], errors='coerce')
    df = datafilter['time'].groupby(datafilter.time.dt.to_period("H")).agg('count')
```

Print gives me:

```
2021-08-18 01:00    20
2021-08-18 02:00     8
2021-08-18 03:00     8
2021-08-18 04:00    13
2021-08-18 05:00    15
2021-08-18 06:00    17
2021-08-18 07:00    23
2021-08-18 08:00    27
2021-08-18 09:00    27
2021-08-18 10:00    28
2021-08-18 11:00    17
2021-08-18 12:00    12
```

And no matter how hard i try, I cannot find a way to store this in a way that i want. So, for example, when there is no records in a csv file within 6:00 to 7:00, line with that timestamp will dissapear. How can I made it to print it like this?:

```
2021-08-18 00:00    32
2021-08-18 01:00     0 <---
2021-08-18 02:00     8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) for fill values between:

```
df = datafiltr.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H', key='time'))['time'].count()
```

If need also `00:00` and `12:00` rows before and after use `reindex`:

```
             time   a
0 2021-08-18 01:00:00  20
1 2021-08-18 03:00:00   8
2 2021-08-18 04:00:00  13
3 2021-08-18 05:00:00  15


first = datafiltr['time'].min().normalize()
last = datafiltr['time'].max().normalize() + pd.Timedelta(12, 'H')

r = pd.date_range(first, last, freq='H')

df = datafiltr.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H', key='time'))['time'].count().reindex(r, fill_value=0)
print (df)
2021-08-18 00:00:00    0
2021-08-18 01:00:00    1
2021-08-18 02:00:00    0
2021-08-18 03:00:00    1
2021-08-18 04:00:00    1
2021-08-18 05:00:00    1
2021-08-18 06:00:00    0
2021-08-18 07:00:00    0
2021-08-18 08:00:00    0
2021-08-18 09:00:00    0
2021-08-18 10:00:00    0
2021-08-18 11:00:00    0
2021-08-18 12:00:00    0
Freq: H, Name: time, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

sample data:

```
dt,col
2021-08-18 01:00,20
2021-08-18 02:00,8
2021-08-18 04:00,13
2021-08-18 05:00,15
2021-08-18 10:00,28
2021-08-18 11:00,17
```

solution

```
import pandas as pd

# load data
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", sep=",").reset_index(drop=True)

# cast type
df["dt"] = df["dt"].apply(pd.Timestamp)
hour_start =  pd.Timestamp("2021-08-18 00:00:00")
hour_end = pd.Timestamp("2021-08-18 12:00:00")

# use start and end to create index
index = pd.date_range(start=hour_start, end=hour_end, freq="H")

# use index to merge sampled data so you have 0 values for missing hours
pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(index, columns=["dt"]), df, how="left", on="dt").fillna(0)
```